# com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Token is not for this app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to generate custom token in server then verifying it. I would like to reuse Firebase authentication token across my app for api security.

Just for testing I have this code which I get from Firebase docs. [Creating Custom Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), [Verifying ID Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens)

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setServiceAccount(sce.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/serviceAccountKey.json"))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://[project-id].firebaseio.com/")
        .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken("the-great-uid")
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String customToken) {

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(customToken)
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Exception excptn) {
                                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "fail verification", excptn);
                                done.set(true);
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
                                String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
                                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "SUCCESS VERIFICATION: ");
                                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "UUDI: {0}", uid);
                                done.set(true);
                            }

                        });

                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Custom token: {0}", customToken);
                done.set(true);
            }
        });

while (!done.get());
```

What Im getting:

```
[INFO] INFO: Custom token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJ******
[INFO] After custom token
[INFO] Nov 17, 2016 3:15:27 PM com.adslide.backend.listeners.AdslideContextListener$1$2 onFailure
[INFO] com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Token is not for this app
[INFO]  at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FirebaseTokenVerifier.verifyTokenAndSignature(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:52)
[INFO]  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$1.call(FirebaseAuth.java:150)
[INFO]  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$1.call(FirebaseAuth.java:144)
[INFO]  at com.google.firebase.tasks.Tasks$1.run(Tasks.java:63)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackgroundThreadFactory$1$1.run(BackgroundThreadFactory.java:60)
```

Did I missed something? I am using Google Appengine.. Please assume I provided the correct `project-id` and `serviceAccountKey.json`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no one had tried to give this a shot. I would like to share what I found, for someone that might came across in this problem too.

I just missed the warning in Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

> Warning: The ID token verification methods included in the Firebase Admin SDKs are meant to verify ID tokens that come from the client SDKs, not the custom tokens that you create with the Admin SDKs. See Auth tokens for more information.

It only means that what I did above is not valid since I am just validating a token which I generated by Admin SDK.